# get the name of text view when we long press in text view

Tags: android

I am trying to get the title and position of the `TextView` when I long press it. But the

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = 
        (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
```

throw null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ,if I understand your question , maybe you need something like this

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info=(AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    int pos = info.position;


}
```

Comment: which listener i can't understand

Comment: Your AdapterView does not take the data from an Adapter object? Inside the adapter object is a getView method that is called every time you see an item of the AdapterView

Comment: Bro sorry for inconvenient but can you give the code for it.

Comment: can you post the code of your AdapterView in the question? or the instantiation of the item?

Comment: registerForContextMenu(textview1); it is in oncreate and above is the all code which is use

Comment: sorry Bro but this code give me null pointer exception. I have already try it.